# Jquery nicescroll from other tab remain active if open a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using [jquery nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)

I apply possibility to scroll to the tables with multiple registrations in it. There are many tables and each one is placed in  different tab. The issue is that when I open a tab were table doesn't have this scroll it remains from the previous one , it looks like some issues with z-index

see screenshots

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware it doesn't directly answer your issue but you could look into custom scrollbars with webkit (if you only run on chrome/safari) instead of using * * * * * * jquery plugins. Here are some links:

http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/
http://davidwalsh.name/custom-scrollbars

About your problem: inspect the scrollbar using the chrome dev tools and check its z-index? Try to alter it and see what happens?

Comment: the probles is that this project should work on ie7+ I cannot use custom scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Answered here with an example for Boostrap 3, It should work also on your case, you just need to change the classes and id names with the ones on your code.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643506/2209086